# Google Cloud Datastore: CI/CD of index.yaml file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Google Cloud Datastore needs to be updated with index.yaml so it can properly index its data.

I am trying to find out what is the proper way to CI/CD indexes on Datastore, as I new features against the emulator, I notice that the index.yaml file gets updated accordingly.

If I include the index.yaml as part of my CI/CD process and run it on each deployment will it have any performance effect even if there is no change to the index file.

Or should we run it only if there is a change to the file, if so whats the ideal way to include it as part of CI/CD

Comment: is [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/indexconfig) what you are asking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> To create or update the indexes that your app's use, you upload the index.yaml configuration file to Cloud Datastore. Indexes that don't exist yet are created after that configuration file is uploaded.

If the file doesn't have new indexes, nothing happens.